# Difference between List<Action> and ActionSequence in jqwik

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests, jqwik

What exactly is the difference in between `List<Action>` and [`ActionSequence`](https://github.com/jlink/jqwik/blob/main/api/src/main/java/net/jqwik/api/stateful/ActionSequence.java) in [jqwik](https://github.com/jlink/jqwik).

In the doc of [jqwik](https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html), `ActionSequence` is created using `Arbitraries.sequences(...)` and the `List<Action>` is created using `Arbitraries.oneOf().list()`

Since the purpose of `ActionSequence` and `List<Action>` is to provide a combination of actions to run after each other.

Please guide me.
Thanks :)

Comment: ActionSequence has methods specific to running all those actions on it, while a List must be iterated item-by-item.

Comment: @Michael What you mentioned is right but it's about how the client uses it, other than that do you know any impactful point? like when to choose which one? or both are just the same but different data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `ActionSequence` if you want to do stateful testing. It has the Build-in capability to use an Action‘s precondition, and its shrinking behaviour is optimized for that use case. If you‘d use `List<Action>` instead, you would have to rebuild all that.

In case you need an introduction of how to use it, look at https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#stateful-testing. More details can be found in https://blog.johanneslink.net/2018/09/06/stateful-testing/ and https://johanneslink.net/model-based-testing/.

Comment: if my actions class does not contain the pre-conditions, then it works the same as `List<Action>`? or it's still preferable to use `ActionSquence`?

Comment: @SagarKhurana Shrinking would still typically be more effective with `ActionSequence`.